# Multiple instances of a module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, process, kernel-modules

I used `cat /proc/modules` to list the process details. Below module shows as 4 instances are present:

```
poe_isr 3046 4 - Live 0xc37e1000 (O)
```

What does it mean? How do I see where these instances are being used?
If the module is shwoing as 0 instances and Live, what does it mean? Module not loaded still Live?

```
adcmods 1565 0 - Live 0xc37dd000 (P)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a counter. It can be incremented or decremented by the kernel core API.

It is the responsibility of the modules, when do they increment it. For example, if you have a `somefs` module in the kernel, then the awaited behavior is to increment this counter with any mount of a `somefs` partition, and decrement it on unmount. On this way, `somefs` can guarantee that it won't be removed while there is a mounted `somefs` partition.

If the module usage counter is non-zero, `rmmod` fails on that module. But `rmmod -f` not, if forced module removal is compiled into the kernel.

Thus, the important things:

- The increment and decrement of the counter is the responsibility of the modules, *there is no sophisticated, generic reference tracking behind it*.
- In many cases, it works correctly, but not always. For example, some dirty modules, like `ipv6` works on that way, that it increases the counter to 1 on `insmod` and never decreases. Thus, if you compiled `ipv6` as module, you won't be ever able to `rmmod` it. Some video card driver works on similar way, because its routines what would deinitialize it, are missing. No such module can be a source of pride for its developers.
- If you can't remove a module because of this, there is no general way to find out, what is exactly used by a module.

Comment: Does it mean that "poe_isr 3046 4 - Live 0xc37e1000 (O)" has only 1 instance currently running? How about "adcmods 1565 0 - Live 0xc37dd000 (P)" ? Here its 0 instance but Live, what does this indicate?

Comment: @Ravi The question is, what you understand on "instance" here. If you understand on it: "how many times is it linked into kernel space", the answer is 1, and always 1, for all the modules, ever, independently from that usage counter number.

Comment: yes you got it right.

Answer (score 1):

```
poe_isr 3046 4 - Live 0xc37e1000 (O)
```

3rd column in this indicates that there are 4 dependent modules/processes. Hence `rmmod` won't work. 4th column indicates whether these are modules or non-modules. '-' indicates that 4 are non-modules. In the above example, poe_isr is dependent on 4 non-modules.